# NDB Querying results that contain a string

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Working with NDB from Google App Engine, I'm looking for all items that contain in any part a given string from the user. Example:

Input: "time"

Output: "retime", "time-trial", "airtime-billing", for example.

I have seen in the question "NDB querying results that start with a string" a similar problem, but it only deals with the starting part. I have implemented it and it works; but i need to complete it with the other parts. I'm working in Python.

In the question I refer in the question, the author does something similar to I'm looking for.

In addition, reading the documentation of search API it's only for documents, and I'm not
handling documents, and I don't want it.

Do you have any suggestions to achieve it?

I get an important advance taking as reference the question mentioned before, and I get the answer.

I write the code used:

```
ndb.OR(ndb.AND(Kind.property >= "time", Kind.property <= "time" + "z"),
       ndb.AND(Kind.property >= "time", Kind.property <= "z" + "time"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in the ndb , you should use search api of google app engine:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/

Comment: yes, the point of that is full text search so it's exactly relevant.